# Ineo 363 - Installation

Tags: drivers, printing

How can i Install the Driver for Ineo 363 on my Ubuntu Machine. My version is 14.04 LTS.

Driver Link is mentioned for reference
https://www.develop.eu/en/support/download-centre.html

Answer (score 0):

so in that link[image]

click on the Driver and download the zip file

[image]

then open a terminal; copy each command below; paste each line into the terminal and hit the ENTER key after each paste; (paste into the terminal is 3 keys held down: control and alt and v)

```
cd Downloads

unzip GE42BW4PPDLinux_MU.zip

cd GE42BW4PPDLinux_/English/CUPS1.2

sudo cp 42BW-4opn.ppd  42BW-4UX.ppd /usr/share/ppd
```

hopefully that will work;

then go to the PRINTERS folder;

click the ADD button to add the 363 to the register;

look for the button that says "Specify PPD file" then when the system asks you where it is,

.. point it to /usr/share/ppd and see if it works with 42BW-4UX.ppd